# Is there any code can fix arabic words display problem?

Tags: python, nlp

i have a string and i want to fix it with python code, I tried to use reshape and it didn't work

```
string = "ﻕﺎﻧﻮﻧ"
```

the word must be like this

```
قانون
```

this is the lib I use and didn't work
arabic-reshaper

```
text_to_be_reshaped = "ﻕﺎﻧﻮﻧ"
reshaped_text = arabic_reshaper.reshape(text_to_be_reshaped)
```

Comment: arabic_reshaper replaces Arabic Unicode characters with their representational forms, but you also need to reorder the characters from logical order to visual order using the python-bidi package.

Answer (score 0):

if your are using windows can install arabic language pack for arabic keyboad[install arabic language pack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ymnNx.png)

Comment: or you can use unicode for arabic language.

Comment: I'm using fedora and this is not the only word, I receive the data from json file and contain a lot from this

Comment: Is your json data is in arabic format ? are your converting it from another once?

Comment: @Taha, I assume he is trying to print Arabic python in a terminal, and most terminals have no bidi support.